# NHibernate: how to transform List<object> returned by a stored procedure to List<Entity> using IQuery?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, nhibernate, transformation, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

Following is my stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetProducts_SP]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Products
END
```

And this is my code:

```
// This code works
IList<ProductsEntity> list = session.QueryOver<ProductsEntity>().List<ProductsEntity>();

// This also works; I get expected data in `object`
string sql = null;
sql = "EXEC GetProducts_SP";
IQuery query = session.CreateSQLQuery(sql);
IList<object> listSP = query.List<object>();
```

As `session.QueryOver` is working fine, there is no problem in entity definition or mapping. That is why, I am not posting table definition, entity class and mappings.

As shown in code above, I properly get the data in `List<object>` from the stored procedure.
Further, I want to convert this `object` data to entity.
To do that, I use this code:

```
//Following fail
IList<ProductsEntity> listSPEntity = query
    .List<ProductsEntity>();
```

This fails with an exception:

> System.ArgumentException: The value "System.Object[]" is not of type "ProductsEntity" and cannot be used in this generic collection.

This seems obvious as NHibernate cannot on itself convert `object` to entity.
So I used transformer to instruct NHibernate how to do that with below code:

```
// This fails
IList<ProductsEntity> listSPEntity = query
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
    .List<ProductsEntity>();
```

This fails with an exception:

> System.ArgumentException: The value "True" is not of type "ProductsEntity" and cannot be used in this generic collection.

How to transform a `List<object>` returned by the stored procedure to `List<Entity>` using `IQuery`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Transformers.DistinctRootEntity` is surely not right tool here. This transformer expects already prepared entities in results. And without `AddEntity` call, you have array of `object`s returned by your procedure like `new object[]{10, "Name", true}`.

With `ISQLQuery` you have to manually register returned entity via `AddEntity` call:

```
string sql = null;
sql = "EXEC GetProducts_SP";
var results = session.CreateSQLQuery(sql)
                .AddEntity(typeof(ProductsEntity).FullName)
                .List<ProductsEntity>();
```

Please note `AddEntity` is available in `ISQLQuery` returned by `CreateSQLQuery`. It's not available with `IQuery` which you use in example.